# How can a not null constraint be dropped?

Tags: mysql, null, constraints

Let's say there's a table created as follows:

```
create table testTable ( colA int not null )
```

How would you drop the not null constraint? I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
ALTER TABLE testTable ALTER COLUMN colA DROP NOT NULL;
```

which is what it would look like if I used PostgreSQL. To my amazement, as far as I've been able to find, the MySQL docs, Google and yes, even Stackoverflow (in spite of dozens or hundreds of NULL-related questions) don't seem to lead towards a single simple SQL statement which will do the job.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
ALTER TABLE testTable MODIFY COLUMN colA int;
```

Comment: For some reason, `alter table testTable modify col int default null` didn't appear to work when I tried it: the above is in fact the right statement, although withouth the single quotes (I'm removing them to match what worked).

Answer (score 18):

In MySQL, nullability is a part of the datatype, not a constraint. So:

```
ALTER TABLE testTable MODIFY COLUMN colA int null;
```

Comment: `alter table x alter column a int null` returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int null' at line 1 [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=1064]"
I also tried `alter table testTable modify a int default null;` and `alter table x alter column a int default null`: the result is the same. I'm using mysql 5.1.

Comment: Sorry, it's `MODIFY COLUMN`, not `ALTER`. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax was close its actually:

```
ALTER TABLE testTable CHANGE colA colA int null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE test.tbl_employee 
CHANGE COLUMN `DepartmentId` `DepartmentId` INT(11) NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE testTable MODIFY COLUMN columnA int;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you modify table constraint or datatype in Mysql workbench then it shows the code it is going to execute to complete the request.
And this is the query I got from that box.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`.`column_name`  CHANGE COLUMN `column_name` `colunm_name`datatype NULL ;
```

But the catch here is that you can't have the primary key as null you have to set it unique instead.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name DROP NOT NULL;
```